# validated multiple nested array items in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i have a nested array to validate which i looked at other questions and valited that . but my problem begins when i multiple the array like below :

```
{
    "items": [
      {
            "sender": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName",


            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "weight": {
                        "value": 1000
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            "sender": {
                "firstName": "firstName",
                "lastName": "lastName",


            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "weight": {
                        "value": 1000
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

now what i want to do is to validate `senders` and `value` to exists and check types of them .
what i have tried so far is :
first i  send the `$data = $request->get('items');` to the validator and then .

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "sender.*.firstName" => "required|string|max:17",
```

but i all the time get this error on validation :

```
{
    "detail": "",
    "message": {
        "sender.lastName.firstName": [
            "sender.lastName.firstName is required."
        ],
```

can you please give some advice how should i validate that array ?? thanks

Comment: it's `items.*.sender.firstName` You have to put the * where the array is.

Comment: its not working and when i get $data the `items` index have been removed.

Comment: Well it should not be removed. You can try `*.sender.firstName` but i'm not sure if it will work, i think it needs a toplevel field

Comment: ok thanks it worked thats all fine :)) you can answer that i accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `items.*.sender.firstName`. You have to put the * where the array is

You should not remove items from the data.

You can try `*.sender.firstName` but i'm not sure if it will work, i think it needs a toplevel field